# Binding all subdomains to single domain in windows server

Tags: dns, subdomain, windows-server-2012, windows-server

I have made my A record in dns

```
*.mysite.com      A      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (the ip)
```

Now at my server I want to bind all of the subdomains to www.mysite.com
binding does not allow using *.mysite.com but allows using * and it works as I want to. but the problem is that it binds other websites on the server too.

by the way:

```
   *.mysite.com    CNAME     www.mysite.com
```

does not work and I don't know why.

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Technically wildcarding the CNAME is possible. But some DNS providers do not support it (like GoDaddy does not support that). Can you find from your DNS provider?

Comment: well as my test has failed mine does not support as well. but wildcards for A records work

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari how about changing name servers of the domain and using glue record and use wild card cname in my own server dns? would it work?

Comment: Not sure if I am getting it right. When you add "your own" NameServers, then the DNS requests would reach to your NS. Are you planning to run your own DNS software on the glued NameServers?

Comment: what I meant to do is to give each user a subdomain. for example user **ashkan** will have the subdomain **ashkan.mysite.com** all these domains should point to the same website and the website gets the username from the url's host and gets the content for that user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating default website bibding it to an empty hostname this does what I want but the problem is all other domains that are pointing to my server, If not binded to anything will be directed to the same site, but this is not a problem in my case.